# Modify SANE backend for Canoscan 9000F scanner to allow A4 width scans longer than 11.7 inches

Tags: scanner, sane

I'm new here so please forgive me if I'm not doing things right. I was hoping someone could help me. I am trying to modify a Canoscan 9000F scanner so that I can scan A4 width documents of any length beyond 11.7 inches. I can modify the scanner enclosure and extend or replace the glass platter. I need help with modifying the sane backend driver. Does anyone know if this is possible? How would I go about doing this? Any suggestions would be most welcome. Thanks.

Mike

Answer (score 0):

The `sane` backend for the CanoScan 9000F is the `pixma` backend. The source code is available, so it should be modifiable.

There are a few point that you should note however.

- an A4 is 11.7 inches long. A longer document is not called A4 anymore; A4 has fixed measurements.
- The firmware of the scanner might also need to be modified
- With flatbed scanners, the sensor's mechanical movement must also be extended, not just the glass plate.

You would probably be better off buying an A3 scanner.

Comment: Hi Ljm Dullaart, thanks for you suggestions. I want to use this particular model because the CCD sensor is excellent and the scanner is cheap so I can afford to break it and experiment. I'm finding it really hard to find technical information on scanner internals. I can't believe that I'm the only person who has thought to try this. There must be others.